# Admin User Grid Not Showing

Tags: magento2.3, grid, ui-grid

After upgrading magento to 2.3.2 I can't see the Admin User Grid anymore.
[image]
System Log Shows This error

> [2019-07-01 10:22:00] main.CRITICAL: Item
>   (Magento\User\Model\User\Interceptor) with the same ID "4" already
>   exists. [] []

I'm still quite new to Magento and have no idea what this ID refers to

I've checked the `admin_user` table in database and all seems to be fine. No duplicate IDs. I'm guessing it's some other table but I have no idea which.
[image]
Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Suggest to try with upgrade and compile command.

Comment: i have tried

setup:upgrade, setup:di:compile, indexer:reindex, setup:static-content:deploy

and removing
generated
var
and pub static folders... with no improvement

Comment: Do you have any join with user table here?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. I haven't been altering anything in magento code.

And all the third party plugins worked fine in 2.3.1.

I have no clue where to look for what's causing this.

Comment: I've also just noticed it might be something else, a js error

I'm getting this error in the console

TypeError: $(...).down(...) is undefined

in grid.js:427:66

It is the only page in admin panel that has this error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone searches this

OK, appears that the issue was caused by a duplicate records in the **authorization_role** table

i have 7 admins and 3 integrations so i should have

3 integration roles
**7** admin user roles
and 1 admin role

instead i had

3 integration roles
**9** admin user roles
and 1 admin role